# My php does not get the post from $.ajax function

Tags: php, ajax, post

i have been searching and researching lots of of similar questions but i haven't found the answer to fix my problem.

The thing is i want to insert data to a MySQL database by using the $.ajax function.

I use a form (form.php), a script to insert the data (insert.php) and my script update.js to call ajax to insert the data (it should be insert.js ... i know but never mind ... )

Here is my form.php:

```
<?php //form.php
//script con un formulario
//conexion a la BD:
include_once 'connect.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
?>
<script type="" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="" src="update.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h3>Ejemplo de forma para actualizar datos con ajax</h3>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <h3>This is the nav area</h3>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <form action="insert.php" name="myform" id="myform">
            <fieldset>
            <legend> Insert new data:</legend>
            <label for="name"> Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name"> </label> <br>
            <label for="age"> Age: <input type="number" id="age" name="age"> </label> <br>
            <label for="company"> Company: <input type="text" id="company" name="company"></label> <br>
            <label for="submit"><input type="submit" value="save" id="submitButton" name="submitButton"></label>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <div id="msg"></div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the insert.php:

```
    <?php //insert.php
//script to insert data (sent via ajax) into database
//conexion a la BD:
include_once 'connect.php';
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    //process data
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $age=$_POST['age'];
    $company=$_POST['company'];
    if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO people (name,age,company) VALUES('$name',$age,'$company')")){
        echo '<p style="color: green;">Data inserted successfully!</p>';
    } else{
        echo '<p style="color: red;">There has been an error: <b>'.mysql_error().'</b></p>';
        die(mysql_error());
    }
} else{
    echo '<p style="color: red;">No data received :(</p>';
}
?>
```

And finally here is my .js code
update.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#submitButton').on('click', function(){
       //retrieving the data submitted:
       var name = $('#name').val();
       var age = $('#age').val();
       var company = $('#company').val();
       alert('The following data is about to be sent: 1) Name: '+ name + '. 2)Age: '+ age + '. 3)Company: '+ company);
       $.ajax({
           url: 'insert.php',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {
               name: name,
               age : age,
           company : company
           },
           'beforeSend':function(){
               alert('Ya los voy a enviar, eh?');
           },
           'success': function(result){
               $('#myform').hide();
               $('#msg').html(result);
               alert('Success!');
           },
           'error': function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
           }
       });//end of ajax
   });
});
```

Where is the code wrong???
I can't get it to work :(

Please help!

Comment: Are you certain that the button click method being called?

Comment: Yes, i am, since i get the alert confirming that ajax has retrieved the data in each variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending the value of the variable from your form, as the name of the variable in your post data. Wrap in quotes should fix your issue.

```
       data: {
           'name' : name,
           'age' : age,
           'company' : company
       },
```

Comment: Do not forget the dataType.

Comment: It didn't work :( I tried the quotes and still does not work. In the form, does it matter whether i leave the action="" (empty) or action="insert.php"? Moreover, the url changes to this: insert.php?name=Marc+Antony&age=36&company=Salsa&submitButton=save

Comment: No, because ajax intercepts the true form action.

Comment: If the URL changes, there must be some JavaScript error occurring now. Or, you need to add `return false;` so your button does not submit the form.

Comment: Btw you don't need the include in the form.php. Also, change the names of the variables you are using to store the names of the DOM elements, so they don't mess with the names of the data.

Comment: Now after adding method="POST", it solves the problem of the URL. But still, it does not work. It does when i set action="insert.php" but it makes the insert.php script to be executed causing that the ajax file be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your form:

```
<form action="insert.php" name="myform" id="myform" method="POST">
```

You forgot the method used for the form to transfer the data. You are expecting POST in PHP and the default if GET.

Also, if you are using a `<form>`, there is no need to use jQuery (as far as i can see).
The form.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
?>
<script type="" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="" src="update.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <h3>Ejemplo de forma para actualizar datos con ajax</h3>
</header>
<nav>
    <h3>This is the nav area</h3>
</nav>
<section>
    <form action="insert.php" name="myform" id="myform" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
        <legend> Insert new data:</legend>
        <label for="name"> Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name"> </label> <br>
        <label for="age"> Age: <input type="number" id="age" name="age"> </label> <br>
        <label for="company"> Company: <input type="text" id="company" name="company"></label> <br>
        <label for="submit"><input type="submit" value="save" id="submitButton" name="submitButton"></label>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div id="msg"></div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submitButton').on('click', function() {
    //retrieving the data submitted:
    var name1 = $('#name').val();
    var age1 = $('#age').val();
    var company1 = $('#company').val();
    alert('The following data is about to be sent: 1) Name: ' + name1 + '. 2)Age: ' + age1 + '. 3)Company: ' + company1);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'insert.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            name: name1,
            age: age1,
            company: company1
        },
        'beforeSend': function() {
            alert('Ya los voy a enviar, eh?');
        },
        'success': function(result) {
            $('#myform').hide();
            $('#msg').html(result);
            alert('Success!');
        },
        'error': function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    }); //end of ajax
});
});
```

Comment: Oh yes, it works fine when i set the action and method ... but then ajax has nothing to do here ... i want it to insert data without refreshing... that's what i really want. The 'success' part of $.ajax never loads.

Comment: Remove the Form, just leave the contents and try it. Tell me what happens.